# JavaScript error with splitting string into array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, file

I am running into an issue with splitting a string into an array. To help myself troubleshoot the problem, I included two alert() functions, but only one gets called. Therefore, I know that there is an issue splitting a string into an array (for a basic username/password check). Here is my JS code:

```
function check() {
var user = document.loginform.usr.value;
var pass = document.loginform.psw.value;
var valid = false;

var txt = new XMLHttpRequest();
var alltext = "";
var allLines = [];
var usrn = [];
var pswd = [];

txt.open("GET", "/c.txt", true);

alltext = txt.responseText;
allLines = alltext.split(/\r\n|\n/);

usrn = allLines[0].split(',');
alert("usrn split");
pswd = allLines[1].split(',');
alert("pswd split");

for (var i=0; i <usrn.length; i++) {
    if ((user == usrn[i]) && (pass == pswd[i])) {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(valid) {
    window.location = "test.html";
    return false;
}else{
    var div = document.getElementById("login");
    div.innerHTML = '<font color="red" size=2><i>Invalid Username/Password!</i></font><br>' + div.innerHTML;
}
```

}

The file that contains the login credentials (c.txt) is as follows:

```
User1,User2
pass,password
```

When User1 enters his/her name into the form, the password should be "pass". However, the script gets stopped at "pswd = allLines[1].split(',');". Am I misunderstanding the lines array?

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: __Asynchronous__ Javascript And Xml.

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean? Is an async thread really going to interfere with a string split?

Comment: No, but `txt.responseText` is not defined at the time you're trying to use it.

Comment: @Teemu oooh okay I see. I'm missing a line then? What might that be? xD

Comment: There are answers with working solutions below, just pick yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a synchronous call by changing the line to

```
txt.open("GET", "/c.txt", false);
```

Or use the "onreadystatechange" event to get the response when the server returns it

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alltext = txt.responseText;
    allLines = alltext.split(/\r\n|\n/);

    usrn = allLines[0].split(',');
    alert("usrn split");
    pswd = allLines[1].split(',');
    alert("pswd split");

    for (var i=0; i <usrn.length; i++) {
        if ((user == usrn[i]) && (pass == pswd[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valid) {
        window.location = "test.html";
        return false;
    }else{
        var div = document.getElementById("login");
        div.innerHTML = '<font color="red" size=2><i>Invalid Username/Password!</i></font><br>' + div.innerHTML;
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if that solves my problem. I'm mainly trying to focus on that pswd = allLines[1].split(','); line. That's where I think everything is going wrong. When I run the script I DO get a "usrn split" alert, but never a "pswd split" alert. I'm guessing there isn't an allLines[1] entry, because if I change it to 0, the "pswd split" message appears. Am I splitting it wrong, or is the readyState line really that important?

Comment: If you console.log(alltext), what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `txt.send()`. Also it is async so `txt.responseText` will most likely be null.

You can use `onreadystatechanged` like so to ensure that `txt.responseText` has a value:

```
txt.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txt.readyState == 4) { // 4 = DONE
        alert(txt.responseText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - after fiddling with the code and doing some more research, I got a working script. This script takes data from a form and checks it against a file (c.txt). If the form entries match a username/password combination in c.txt, it takes you to another webpage.

```
function check() {
var user = document.loginform.usr.value;
var pass = document.loginform.psw.value;
var valid = false;

var txt;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
     txt = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    txt = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var allLines = [];
var usrn = [];
var pswd = [];

txt.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(txt.readyState==4 && txt.status==200){
        var alltext = txt.responseText;
        allLines = alltext.split(/\r\n|\n/);

        usrn = allLines[0].split(',');
        pswd = allLines[1].split(',');

        for (var i=0; i <usrn.length; i++) {
            if ((user == usrn[i]) && (pass == pswd[i])) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(valid) {
            window.location = "test.html";
            return false;
        }else{
            var div = document.getElementById("login");
            div.innerHTML = '<font color="red" size=2><i>Invalid Username/Password!</i></font><br>' + div.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

txt.open("GET", "c.txt", false);
txt.send();
```

}